# Google Script does not trigger Email Alert although no bugs are present

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

My script does not show any errors, however it does not trigger my script either. The whole idea is to sent an email to me whenever yesterday's date shows a value greater than 0.5 in column F. So very straight forward.

**Here is the code:**

```
function readCell() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('crashes');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange()
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var yesterday=new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth(),new Date().getDate()-1);
  var yesterdayString=Utilities.formatDate(yesterday, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyyMMdd")

  for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++) {//Start at one if you have a header line
    if (isDate(vA[i][3])) {
      var t1=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(vA[i][3]),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"yyyyMMdd");

      if(t1==yesterdayString && Number(vA[i][5])>=0.5) {
        MailApp.sendEmail('sss@gmail.com','Alert', 'Result found on: ' + Number(i+1))
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(i+1);
      }
    }
  }
}


function isDate(date){
  return(Object.prototype.toString.call(date) === '[object Date]');
}
```

**Here is the data itself from a Google Sheet.** 
As you can see, on Jan 12th when I tested it, the script should have triggered for Jan 11th an email alert to me because column F shows 0.7 (greater than 0.5) but it didnt.

[image]
Can someone help me understand why this script does not find any data?

Comment: Although I'm not sure about your actual Spreadsheet, about ``Date->Column D, Value->Column F``, if "Date" is the column "C", ``if (isDate(vA[i][3])) {}`` which is used for comparing the column "D" always becomes ``False``. So the script in the if statement is not run. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike So, i updated my Google Sheet screenshot to show the column names better that go with the Date and Value. So, I do not have a concern that Date is in column C. It is indeed in column D as expected. Would you have any other thoughts?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize that my comment was not useful.

Comment: Is this question any different than your last 3 questions all on the same exact topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some difficulty comparing dates but worked it out. Try something like this using the Date valueOf() method.  I'm not sure what you need isDate for unless you have a mixed up column.

```
function test() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var rg=sh.getRange("B1:C1");
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  Logger.log(vA);
  var today = new Date();
  var yesterday = new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),today.getDate()-1);

  for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++) {//Start at one if you have a header line
    var value = vA[i][0];
    if( (new Date(value.getFullYear(),value.getMonth(),value.getDate()).valueOf() == yesterday.valueOf()) && (Number(vA[i][1]) >= 0.5)) {
      //MailApp.sendEmail('sss@gmail.com','Alert', 'Result found on: ' + Number(i+1))
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(i+1);
    }
  }
}


function isDate(date){
  return(Object.prototype.toString.call(date) === '[object Date]');
```

}

Comment: Thanks, but I get this error:TypeError: Cannot find function getFullYear in object 20180609. (line 41, file "MenuSetup").

Comment: for "Number(vA[i][1])" What do you refer to with [1]? Would that be column B for the value?

Comment: Then the values in your column D are not dates.  Maybe strings?

Comment: How can I test if the values are string VS date?

Comment: Why not just make sure the values in that column are dates?

Comment: That’s what the problem was! My dates were numbers not dates! lol

Comment: Then you isDate would always return false.